# Eigendecomposition as change of bases

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

Is the eigendecomposition generally a change of basis? For a diagonalizable matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ the eigendecomposition is defined as $A = Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$, change of bases is defined as $P^{-1}MP$. If its true, how would you show that the eigendecomposition is a change of bases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigendecomposition is always done through a change of basis.

When the matrix is symmetric, the spectral theorem states that you can diagonalize it in an orthonormal basis, and thus the change of base can be made through $P$ such that $P^{-1} = P^{T}$. But in the general case, this is not true anymore.

The point of the eigendecomposition is to find vectors $(u_1, ..., u_n)$ and eigenvalues $(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$ such that $(u_1, ..., u_n)$ is a base and $A u_i = \lambda_i u_i$. One suitable matrix $P$ is the change of base from canonical to $(u_1, ..., u_n)$. This is the definition ; the case of symmetric matrices is a special case.

(By the way : $(Q \Lambda Q^T)^T = Q \Lambda Q^T \neq Q^T \Lambda Q$ when $Q$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ diagonal, except for specific values of $Q, \Lambda$.)

Comment: youre absolutely right, my bad, thats embarrassing xD thanks for your help!